# zbar sdk not scanning bar code for iphone 4.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios4, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I am using zbar sdk in my project but it is not scanning barcode for iphone 4.0.1 so can anyone suggest me proper way ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ZBar SDK in iPhone 4.0. It works like charm, follow all the steps mentioned in installation guide, it will work perfectly.

[check this link for help](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html)